# iOS uiwebview magnifying glass keydown event

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview for text editor. And I want to know font status in cursor location. So I had onkeyup event on div like this

```
<div id='content' overflow-y='no' contenteditable='true'
    onKeyDown='callObjFunction()' onkeyup='callKeyUpFunction()' >
</div>
```

and got callback on moving the content cursor with keyboard, But I can't get call on ios UIWebview magnifying glass moved the cursor event, like this.

[image]

For I know there is a solution to detect touches to the uiwebview. But I want to know is there no html js callback to this event? any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) 
{window.location='js-settarget:runTypeMethod';}, false);
```

that would communicate with objective-c function on magnifying glass up.